# php - find value in multi array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I tried to find a value in an multi array but without any success

this the array in a foreach loop:

```
$post['old_IDs'][] = array(
    'page_title' => $post['post_title'],
    'post_id' => $post['post_id']
);

 update_option('page_IDs',$post['old_IDs']); // I store it (for wordpress)
```

and I tried to search inside it after the foreach loop:

```
$old_IDs = get_option('page_IDs');
foreach($old_IDs as $key => $val) {
   if ( $val['post_id'] === '1234' ) {
        $page_name = $val['page_title'];
    }
}
```

But it seems to not working...

Comment: try this and post the result please `var_dump($old_IDs);`

Comment: result: $page_name undefined...

Comment: This code is correct, as I see it. Suggestion 1: Try `print_r($post)` or other ways of debugging to check the actual values. Suggestion 2: make sure that `$post` is not cleared/fresh initiated every time (since you read fresh values for `post_title` and `post_id` from `$post` as well as you store those values in `$post`).

Comment: $old_IDs undefined. Strange because in two array I've got the value...

Comment: My $old_IDs have data in fact I can read it directly because i'm in ajax but in json response I got multiple object... I think it comes from my foreach loop to search the value

Comment: I m near sure it comes from the way to search in foreach. If I remove the code inside the foreach search I can get my array with json. But if I execute the loop I get undefined...